# web based firebase code running multiple times when executed

Tags: javascript, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update some data into my Firebase realtime database, but for some reason the code runs multiple times when i present it with a new string, this messes up the output of the code.

Below is what I have tried, I tried to create a new function for the `ref.update()`, but the same thing happens again, I have pointed in the comments of the code where exactly the code goes back to.

```
function fire_base_db() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        r = snapshot.val();
        var ham_db = r.hams.spam_words;
        var spam_db = r.spams.spam_words; //contains spam data now
        console.log('function 1')
        inputstring(ham_db, spam_db);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.code);
    });
}
inputstring(ham_db, spam_db); //just a random function i need 
spam_prop(user_string_toknized, spam_db, ham_db); //yet another 
function spam_or_ham()

function spam_or_ham() {
    var final_value = " ";

    if (total_spam_probablity < total_ham_probablity) {

        console.log("ham");
        final_value = "ham";
    } else {

        console.log("spam");
        final_value = "spam";
    }


    if (final_value = "spam") {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref("hams/spam_words/");

        ref.update(old_words_spam_2);
    } else if (final_value = "ham") {
        var ref2 = firebase.database().ref("spams/spam_words/")
        ref2.update(old_words_ham_2)
    };


    for (var a in new_words_spam) {
        new_words_spam[b] = 1
    }

    for (var b in new_words_ham) {
        new_words_ham[a] = 1;
    }


    if (final_value = "spam") {
        var ref9 = firebase.database().ref("spams/spam_words/")

        ref9.update(new_words_spam)

    } else if (final_value = "ham") {
        var ref2 = firebase.database().ref("hams/spam_words")
        ref2.update(new_words_ham)
    }

}
fire_base_db_upadt_new_words();
fire_base_db_upadt_new_words_2();
```

The first function `fire_base_db()` is used to read data from the database, the next 2 functions are just some steps for the output, the last function `spam_or_ham` is where the bug appears, moment the code enters the `if` statement and reaches the `ref9.update` part, it runs back to `ref.on` in the first function and run multiple times, each time executing till the ref9 part, except in the last execution where the whole code is executed, I want the full code to be executed in the first time itself.

Comment: firebase.ref() will fetch a reference to the root node. This means that any and all updates made to the realtime db will trigger that callback

Comment: What exactly is your use case?

Comment: @ThatBrianDude  the code is used for spam classification , firebase is used to contain the spam words and their count , also after the user email is classifed i want to update the database to include the new words that were encountered by the code